# How to draw a circle around current position?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, awt

I am trying to build a program that allows you to draw a Graph. I am currently trying to add a function to add a node to the graph. My idea is that the user can click a button and then click somewhere on the window to add a node. I face the two following problems now:

1. drawCenteredCircle method needs me to pass a Graphics object, but which one? Since it is an abstract class I cannot simply declare a new instance, so what can I pass?
2. Currently the position of the center of the circle will be the one where the button was clicked. How can I solve this? I want that **AFTER** the button was clicked, the **NEXT** click will add a node. Basically I need a function that waits for another user input and then add this node.

   public class Main extends JFrame {

   ```
   int width = 500;
   int height = 500;
   JLabel label;
   JPanel panel;
   JButton addNodeButton;

   public Main() {
       setSize(width, height);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       panel = new JPanel();
       label = new JLabel();
       addNodeButton = new JButton("Add Node");
       addNodeButton.addActionListener((new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
               drawCenteredCircle(g, p.x, p.y, 3);
           }

       }));
       panel.add(addNodeButton);
       this.add(panel);
       setVisible(true);

   }

   public static void main(String a[]) {
       new Main();
   }

   public void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int r) {
         x = x-(r/2);
         y = y-(r/2);
         g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: 1) *needs me to pass a Graphics object* - that is not the way custom painting is done. You would do custom painting on a JPanel. The Graphics object is passed to the panel for you to use. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) and decide which is the best approach for you.

Comment: 2) * the center of the circle will be the one where the button was clicked.* - then you might do something like a) create an Boolean instance variable to indicate if the "Add Node" button was pressed. b) add a MouseListener to the JPanel. In the mousePressed event you would then check if the variable is true and add the node, then reset the variable to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  The explanations will be forthcoming when you check out the tutorials on painting or consult the Java API.  I used a `mouseListener` instead of a button.  It draws a circle around where you click the button.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int x;
    int y; 
    int diameter = 60;
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }

    public Main() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
              g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        for(Point p : points) {
            g2d.drawOval(p.x,p.y, diameter,diameter);
        }

    }

    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            x = me.getX()-diameter/2;
            y = me.getY()-diameter/2;
            points.add(new Point(x,y));
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Followup question: Why does this run without a main method?

Comment: It has a main method. Right above the Main() constructor.